# Retrieve all the location from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]
[image]
I am newbie using Firebase in android. I want to retrieve the same attribute with different location

```
Query query = demoRef.orderByChild("YEAR & MONTH & NEIGHBORHOOD_ID").equalTo(2016_11_windsor);

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
         // dataSnapshot is the "issue" node with all children with id 0
         for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
             //Map<String, Object> newPost = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
             String geo_lat = (String) data.child("GEO_LAT").getValue();
             String geo_lon = (String) data.child("GEO_LON").getValue();

             demoValue.setText("Latitude: " + geo_lat + ", " + geo_lon);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: can you show your database nodes

Comment: `.equalTo(2016_11_windsor)` This seems invalid code unless you've defined a variable `2016_11_windsor`. Did you forget to put quotes around what is intended to be a string?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: How do I put the GEO_LAT and GEO_LON into a file n store it as json file?